# MySQL substring of count(1) error

Tags: mysql, count, substring

I need to count the rows of a table and then substring the result. To get what I need, I tried this:

```
SELECT substring(count(1),1,1) FROM users
```

The following query returns `85`:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM users
```

The first query returns `38` when the expected value is `8`. Why is this happening?

Comment: According to your sql query, it should be `8`. Do you execute this query in your program through a db connect or in some mysql tools?

Comment: I executed the queries with the phpMyAdmin SQL option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
SELECT substring(cast(count(1) as char), 1, 1) FROM users
```

Answer (score 1):

Why it is happening is because the result of `substring` is being implicitly cast as `binary` (I didn't get 38 possibly due to different charset).

```
select count(1) from users;

| count(1) |
|----------|
|       85 |
```

If I use same method as you:

```
select substring(count(1),1,1) from users;

| substring(count(1),1,1) |
|-------------------------|
|                    OA== |
```

is same as if I cast the result as binary:

```
select cast(substring(count(1),1,1) as binary) from users;

| cast(substring(count(1),1,1) as binary) |
|-----------------------------------------|
|                                    OA== |
```

But If I cast result as char, I get correct result:

```
select cast(substring(count(1),1,1) as char) from users;

| cast(substring(count(1),1,1) as char) |
|---------------------------------------|
|                                     8 |
```

same if I cast count(1) as char:

```
select substring(cast(count(1) as char),1,1) from users;

| substring(cast(count(1) as char),1,1) |
|---------------------------------------|
|                                     8 |
```